# Error using griddedInterpolant Interpolation requires at least two sample points for each grid dimension

Tags: matlab

I'm doing an exercise on finding approximate values in Matlab
This is my code:

```
x = 1:5;
y = 1:5;
[x1,y1] = ndgrid(x,y);
r = sqrt(1+3*x+2*y.^2);
F = griddedInterpolant(x,y,r);

cx = 1:0.2:5;
cy = 1:0.2:5;
[cx1,cy1] = ndgrid(cx,cy);
cr = F(cx,cy);
cr = interpn(x,y,r,cx,cy);
surf(x,y,r);figure;surf(cx,cy,cr)
```

I got the error:

```
Error using griddedInterpolant Interpolation requires at least two sample points for each grid dimension.
```

Please help me how to resolve it? thank you!

Comment: Read the error and the docs: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddedinterpolant.html;jsessionid=dc0a480e1d87fa8a960bc718dbd8